# How to grep such that you search only in a list of files

Tags: bash, grep, ksh

I have a list of files in a file called scripts.txt

I want to grep for "runcob" only in the files contained in scripts.txt. I dont want to grep in  other files that are not contained in scripts.txt. How do I do so. Please help. I am planning to use ksh if we need a script for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the list of files and `grep`:

```
while read -r file; do
  grep runcob "${file}"
done < scripts.txt
```

Comment: what does < scripts.txt mean?

Comment: `command < file` execute `command` with `file` as input.  You might also want to refer to [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

Comment: is this ksh? and how to redirect output of runcob to a file

Comment: @Programmer Yes, this would work in ksh.  In order to redirect the output to a file, add `> outputfile` after `scripts.txt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot devnull :D. One last question. What is the input i.e, runcob is also from a file?

Comment: No, the first argument to `grep` is a regular expression; in this case, the literal string "runcob".  (There is no need to quote a string which doesn't contain any shell metacharacters, although it would nevertheless be good form to put it in quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

This is why we have [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs).

```
xargs grep 'runcob' <scripts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames do not contain any spaces, it could be as simple

```
grep runcob $(cat scripts.txt)
```